# How does $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ act on the automorphism group of an elliptic curve?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of number fields; I'm interested mainly in the case $K = \Bbb{Q}$ and $L= \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. Let $X$ be an elliptic curve over $K$ and $\text{Aut}(X_L)$ the  group of $L$ automorphisms of $X_{L}$. Now I have read many times that we can consider the Galois cohomology group $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K),\text{Aut}(X_L))$, but however:

> > Doesn't this require the Galois group to act on $\text{Aut}(X_L)$? I can't seem to see what the action is. I looked in Silverman and Tate's Arithmetic of Elliptic curves, but it I can't find it stated anywhere for what the action is.

Answer (score 7):

The curve $E$ is defined over $K$, so $E_L := \text{Spec } L \times_{\text{Spec } K}
E.$  Thus there is an action of Gal$(L/K)$ on $E_L$, via its action on the first
factor.   (This is the scheme-theoretic interpretation of the action on coefficients
discussed by Hurkyl).  This *not* an action on $E_L$ as an $L$-scheme,
since Gal$(L/K)$ acts non-trivially on $L$.

But now, if $\sigma$ some automorphism of $E_L$ in the category of $L$-schemes,
then the composite $g \sigma g^{-1}$ *will* be another automorphism of $E_L$
in the category of $L$-schemes (i.e. it lies over the identity map on Spec $L$).

This is the definition of the Gal$(L/K)$-action on Aut$(E_L)$.

Comment: Dear Matt, thanks for your answer. Permit me to ask a somewhat stupid question (though which has been bothering me for a while). It is clear to me that $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ acts on $L$ via $K$-automorphisms. However how then does $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ act on $Spec L$, i.e. a morphism ***of schemes*** $\text{Gal}(L/K) \times_K Spec L \to Spec L$? My impression is that $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ should be made into a $K$-scheme by taking $\bigsqcup_{g \in \text{Gal}(L/K)} Spec K$ (cont'd)

Comment: And then $\text{Gal}(L/K) \times_K Spec  L \to spec L$ is the map induced from $L \to  L \times \ldots \times L$ sending $l$ to $(g\cdot l,\ldots,g \cdot l)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @fpqc:Dear fpqc, You could try to realize this action internally in the category of schemes, but there's no need to.  The passage to Spec is functor, so it takes automorphisms of the ring $L$ to automorphisms of its Spec.  Regards,

Comment: any good reference for this? In particular I am interested in the action of the absolute Galois group on the automorphism of curves.

Answer (score 2):

An element of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ induces an automorphism of $X_L$ through its action on the plane over $L$. I imagine the intended action of a Galois element is via conjugation by the automorphism it induces.

Comment: At the moment the answer is not very clear to me. For one, why should $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ act on $\operatorname{Spec} L[x,y]$? (2) the action on $\operatorname{Spec}L[x,y]/(y^2 = f(x))$ is obtained via base change?

Comment: $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ acts on $L[x,y]$ by acting on the coefficients. That is, it induces the homomorphism given by the action $L \to L$ along with the choices $x \to x$ and $y \to y$.

Comment: I'm still confused. If we have an action on coefficients then why do we have an action of the Galois group on Spec; i.e. an action satisfying all the axioms on the set Spec $L[x,y]$?

Comment: Every ring homomorphism $R \to S$ induces a scheme morphism $\operatorname{Spec} S \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ (this is actually a bijective correspondence). A similar statement can be made for the $\operatorname{Proj}$ construction